# Absolute convergence in series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to determine whether the following series is absolut convergent or not. I´m not sure how to begin generally. I would say no, because when taking the absolut value of the fraction and add all of them together the series doesnt converge...could someone give me a general road plan how to manage this.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$

Comment: It seems you already answered it...

Comment: Its like a sine wave infinitely close to real line or x -axis.

Comment: If you're asked to "determine if the series $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent", you're simply being asked "does $\sum |a_n|$ converge?". So, you do exactly as you described in your post. Look at $\sum\Bigl|{(-1)^n\over 2n+1}\Bigr|=\sum{1\over 2n+1}$, and determine if it converges or not. It diverges, as you noted; so, the given series does not converge absolutely. (All you need to do in addition is to *justify* that the sum of the absolute values is indeed divergent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n$ being absolutely convergent is equivalent (defined as) to  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|c_n|$ converging.

So,we compare $|a_n|=|\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}|=\frac{1}{2n+1}$ with $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{b_n}{|a_n|}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2n+1}{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}(2+\frac{1}{n})=2.$$
We know the harmonic series diverges, and conclude by comparison that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ diverges.

More generally, for any $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a}{bn+c}$$ diverges.

Comment: I didn't get you as alternating HM series converges and it is alternating HM.

Comment: @LawjesJaknap But the absolute value is not alternating.. Am I missing something?

Comment: No I think you are correct. It diverges because of p-test with power(n) not being >1.

Comment: @Dror thx for the illustrating example

Comment: Very welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Do a comparison: sum of absolute value of your each term against $\sum \frac{1}{3n}$. Note the latter diverges, because?

Answer (score 0):

Basically two tests are needed to check for convergence in case of alternating series which it is :

a) It is decreasing monotonically.

b) Its limit is 0 as n approaches infinity.

In this, for first check that ,

let $f(x)= \frac { 1 }{ (2n+1) }  $. So,$f'(x) = \frac { -2 }{ (2n+1)^2 } $ which is clearly decreasing monotonically.

For second test, we need to calculate limit of $f(x)={ Lt }_{ n->\infty  }\quad \frac { 1 }{ (2n+1) } $ which is 0. Hence both are satisfied and it converges. But as the other answer has stated it fails for being absolutely convergent on comparing with a more general series, it's p-test gives divergent for power(n) of compared series not being >1.